# SharePoint API - ItemCount shows something but empty list of files and folders

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, folder, api

I'm accessing a SharePoint folder that contains two files and a subfolder.  I'm getting back a correct ItemCount but no list of items.  Using a made-up path of /sites/sitename/folder1/folder1, and hence the following URI:

```
https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')?$expand=Files,Folders
```

The result comes out looking like:

```
{
  "d": {
    "__metadata": {
      "id": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')",
      "uri": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')",
      "type": "SP.Folder"
    },
    "Files": {
      "results": []
    },
    "ListItemAllFields": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/ListItemAllFields"
      }
    },
    "ParentFolder": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": "https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/ParentFolder"
      }
    },
    "Properties": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/Properties"
      }
    },
    "StorageMetrics": {
      "__deferred": {
        "uri": https://myplace.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2')/StorageMetrics"
      }
    },
    "Folders": {
      "results": []
    },
    "Exists": true,
    "IsWOPIEnabled": false,
    "ItemCount": 3,
    "Name": "folder2",
    "ProgID": null,
    "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/sitename/folder1/folder2",
    "TimeCreated": "2023-06-23T12:20:23Z",
    "TimeLastModified": "2023-06-27T11:06:16Z",
    "UniqueId": "12345678-1234-4321-8765-001234567890",
    "WelcomePage": ""
  }
}
```

I can see an ItemCount of 3 there, which seems to reflect my two files and a folder (and that number changes if I add/remove things in the web interface) but why am I getting an empty list of 'Folders' and 'Files'?

I thank you in advance for whatever thing it is that I'm missing!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible to get items from a list this way. The best way to query a list is to use the [RenderListDataAsStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#retrieve-items-as-a-stream) API. You need to specify the `FolderServerRelativeUrl` parameter to limit your query to a folder. You can either use the `ViewXml` parameter to specify a CAML query, starting with a `<View>` element. That is the most flexible option. There is also the simpler FilterValue1 etc. parameters that are user from the SharePoint list web interface.

Comment: Is that a list?  The path I'm using is taken from the web interface where I'm presented with a folder-like display with the files in it.  Since the API is returning a structure with an ItemCount of 3, I was expecting to be able to 'see' those three items.  Somehow...

Comment: From an API perspective, lists and document libraries are the same.

Comment: You're losing me in nomenclature there I'm afraid - I'm new to Sharepoint except for having used it essentially as a file store using the web interface for a while.  I see it as a normal hierarchical structure of folders and documents with some attributes and 'check out/check in' ability.  Hence, I was foreseeing it like a file system where I can give it a reference to a 'folder' and ask for a list of files and folders within that folder.  Seems I may have been too simplistic.